# Multiple single plots in seaborn with pandas groupby data

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

My issue is very specific, i guess, but i can't seem to find a proper solution, and im clueless with the error output that i get.
Anyway, i have a pandas dataframe loaded from an sqlite database.

```
data_frame = pd.read_sql_query(
"SELECT (total_comb + total_comb_rc) as total_comb, p_val, w_length from {tn}".format(
    tn=table_name), conn)
```

With that loaded, i group the data by the 'w_length' value.

```
for i, group in data_frame.groupby('w_length'):
```

Now, i want to plot a scatter plot for each group created with seaborn lmplot.

```
for i, group in data_frame.groupby('w_length'):
    sns.lmplot(x=group['total_comb'], y=group['p_val'],
               data=group,
               fit_reg=False)
    sns.despine()
    plt.savefig('test_scatter'+i+'.png', dpi=400)
```

But for some reason im getting, this output.

```
'[  6.95485628e-02   3.53641178e-01   3.46862200e+06   4.11684800e+06] not in index'
```

and no plot file.
I know im doing something wrong, but i cant seem to figure it out.

pd: i know i can do something like this.

```
sns.lmplot(x='total_comb', y='p_val',
       data=data_frame,
       fit_reg=False,
       hue="w_length", x_jitter=.1, col="w_length", col_wrap=3, size=4)
```

but i also need the separeted plots for each 'w_length'.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please first separate the issue into it's components and find out which of them causes the problem. That is, find out if the data frame you obtain is actually what you expect. If this is the case, produce a mockup dataframe and post a [mcve]. If the sql query does not produce the expected dataframe, remove all the other stuff and instead show us the database structure and the output you get.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, indeed if i posted this code is because all works as expected besides the problem exposed! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the problem is not due to the data collection from the sql database, it's probably due to the fact that you call
 `sns.lmplot(x=group['total_comb'], y=group['p_val'], data=group)`
instead of
 `sns.lmplot(x='total_comb', y='p_val', data=group)`

Here is a working example, which produces two separate plots:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

x = np.arange(24)
y = np.random.randint(1,10, len(x))
cat = np.random.choice(["A", "B"], size=len(x))
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y, "cat": cat})

for i, group in df.groupby('cat'):
    sns.lmplot(x="x", y="y", data=group, fit_reg=False)
    plt.savefig(__file__+str(i)+".png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: That was the issue! I sincerely thank you a lot! I couldn't see it myself!