# Seaborn plot pandas dataframe by multiple groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, seaborn

I have pandas dataframe  where I have nested 4 categories (50,60,70,80) within two categories (positive, negative) and I would like to plot with seaborn kdeplot of a column (eg., A_mean...) based on groupby. What I want to achieve is this [image: picture] (this was done by splitting the pandas to a list). I went over several posts, this code ([Multiple single plots in seaborn with pandas groupby data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888287/multiple-single-plots-in-seaborn-with-pandas-groupby-data)) works for one level but not for the two if I want to plot this for each Game_RS:

```
for i, group in df_hb_SLR.groupby('Condition'):
    sns.kdeplot(data=group['A_mean_per_subject'], shade=True, color='blue', label = 'label name')
```

I tried to use this one ([Seaborn groupby pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279810/seaborn-groupby-pandas-series)) but the first answer did not work for me:

```
sns.kdeplot(df_hb_SLR.A_mean_per_subject, groupby=df_hb_SLR.Game_RS)

AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'groupby'
```

and the pivot answer I was not able to make work.
Is there a direct way from seaborn or any better way directly from pandas Dataframe?

My data are accessible in csv format [under this link -- data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cq1yaUwl5gOfzniHMBB0gehOCIbgnd8o) and I load them as usual:

```
df_hb_SLR = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using seaborn's `FacetGrid`, which makes this kind of things really easy

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df_hb_SLR, col="Condition", hue='Game_RS', height=5, aspect=0.5)
g = g.map(sns.kdeplot, 'A_mean_per_subject', shade=True)
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

The downside of `FacetGrid` is that it creates a new figure, so If you'd like to integrate those plots into a larger ensemble of subplots, you could achieve the same result using `groupby()` and some looping:

```
group1 = "Condition"
N1 = len(df_hb_SLR[group1].unique())
group2 = 'Game_RS'
target = 'A_mean_per_subject'
height = 5
aspect = 0.5
colour = ['gray', 'blue', 'green', 'darkorange']


fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,N1, figsize=(N1*height*aspect,N1*height*aspect), sharey=True)

for (group1Name,df1),ax in zip(df_hb_SLR.groupby(group1),axs):
    ax.set_title(group1Name)
    for (group2Name,df2),c in zip(df1.groupby(group2), colour): 
        sns.kdeplot(df2[target], shade=True, label=group2Name, ax=ax, color = c)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Diziet, thank you very much for your answer. I have two small questions to the 2nd, for loop solution.
1) could you please describe how the looping over groupby objects work? Because

2) I wanted to add custom colour to each game, I tried to generalize your solution to:

```
colour = ['gray', 'blue', 'green', 'darkorange']
...
for (group1Name,df1),ax in zip(df_hb_SLR.groupby(group1),axs):
    ax.set_title(group1Name)
    for (group2Name,df2),colour in zip(df1.groupby(group2), colour):
        sns.kdeplot(df2[target], shade=True, label=group2Name, ax=ax, color = colour)
```

Comment: Your code was almost correct, except that you were using the same name `colour` twice in the for-loop. I've amended my answer.

Comment: One more question. If I change the groups, ie. `group1 = 'Game_RS';
group2 = 'Condition'` and then I want to use 2 rows, 2 cols, `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(N1*height*aspect,N1*height*aspect), sharey=True)`
 I get this error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_title'`. Do you know why and how to fix it? If I use (1,N1), it works. Thanks

Comment: There are many posts about that error. For instance [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111724/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-plot). Basically, if you're doing more that 1 row or 1 column, then the returned object is a 2D numpy array. You can loop using `for (...),ax in zip(..., axs.flat):`